# Calculate average for specific date range in R

Tags: r, date, range, average

I have two data frames:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 17)
x <-data.frame(Date)
x$discharge <- c("1000","1100","1200","1300","1400","1200","1300","1300","1200","1100","1200","1200","1100","1400","1200","1100","1400")
x$discharge <- as.numeric(x$discharge)
```

And:

```
Date2 <- c("2013-01-01","2013-01-08","2013-01-12","2013-01-17")
y <- data.frame(Date2)
y$concentration <- c("1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5")
y$Date2 <- as.Date(y$Date2)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)
```

What I am desperately trying to do is to the following:

1. In data frame y the first measurement is for the period 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-07
2. Calculate the average discharge for this period in data frame x
3. Return the average discharge to data frame y in a new column next to the first measurement and continue with the next measurement

I was having a look into function such as `dplyr` or `apply` but was not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  mutate(period = cut(as.Date(Date), c(as.Date("1900-01-01"), as.Date(y$Date2[-1]), as.Date("2100-01-01")), c(1:length(y$Date2)))) %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
  mutate(meandischarge = mean(discharge, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  right_join(y, by = c("Date" = "Date2"))

        Date discharge period meandischarge concentration
      <date>     <dbl> <fctr>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 2013-01-01      1000      1      1214.286           1.5
2 2013-01-08      1300      2      1200.000           2.5
3 2013-01-12      1200      3      1200.000           1.5
4 2013-01-17      1400      4      1400.000           3.5
```

If you only want the original y variables, you could do this:

```
x %>% 
  mutate(period = cut(as.Date(Date), c(as.Date("1900-01-01"), as.Date(y$Date2[-1]), as.Date("2100-01-01")), c(1:length(y$Date2)))) %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
  mutate(meandischarge = mean(discharge, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  right_join(y, by = c("Date" = "Date2")) %>% 
  select(Date2 = Date, concentration, meandischarge)
       Date2 concentration meandischarge
      <date>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 2013-01-01           1.5      1214.286
2 2013-01-08           2.5      1200.000
3 2013-01-12           1.5      1200.000
4 2013-01-17           3.5      1400.000
```

Comment: I applied your example to my specific code and I get the following error message:
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ

I have two columns in my original "x" data frame but three in my original "y" data frame. Might that cause the problem? Does this relate to c(1:4) in the second line of your code?

Comment: I think I figured it out: The c(1:4) refers to the number of rows in data frame y. However, what happens if the number of rows differs with each new data frame I want to use your code with?

Comment: The 2nd argument of `cut()` refers to the interval boundaries, I took the dates in y. Since the last interval also needs an endpoint, I added `Inf`. The labels `c(1:4)` should have a length of 1 less than the 2nd argument. You could replace the `4` by `length(y$Date2)`

Comment: Just check this: `x <- 1:10`
`cut(x, c(0,3,7,Inf), c("low", "medium", "high"))` This gives: `[1] low    low    low    medium medium medium medium high   high   high  `

Comment: BTW, I have slightly updated the `cut()` function in my code. Perhaps there was a little problem converting Inf to a date, so I have added 1900-01-01 as the earliest date and 2100-01-01 as the latest date.

Comment: As an add-on how would I be able to multiply mean discharge by the number of days between each measurement, e.g. multiply 1214.286 x 7 (number of days between 01.01. and 08.01.2013)? I was thinking of adding another line after mutate as follows: mutate(load = meandischarge*number of days, na.rm = T)) %>%  but I don´t know how to extract number of days.